# How to retrieve crash logs from Windows Phone 8 programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a WP8 App where I want to store the crash logs if and when generated.
Is there any way of fetching the crash dump file from Windows Phone 8 programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't retrieve the crash dumps that are automatically sent to the DevCenter. However, what you can do is subscribing to the global unhandled exception event handler, store the exception contents in the isolated storage, then do whatever you need with it (like sending it to a remote server). That's what many applications do, and it's even automated by some libraries (such as Telerik).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using a logging system as MetroLog. You'll be able to collect these crash logs if you configure GlobalCrashHandler that will  ensure that a FATAL log entry is written if an unhandled exception occurs.

You can install it using NuGet

```
Install-Package MetroLog
```

Here's an quick example:

```
using MetroLog;
using MetroLog.Targets;

LogManagerFactory.DefaultConfiguration.AddTarget(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, new FileStreamingTarget());
GlobalCrashHandler.Configure();

ILogger log = LogManagerFactory.DefaultLogManager.GetLogger<MainPage>();

log.Trace("This is a trace message.");
```

You can find a tutorial explaining how to add it on your project at http://talkitbr.com/2015/06/11/adicionando-logs-em-universal-apps. Also there is an explanation regarding retrieving these logs.